# How to create parent and childs in a has many through relation in a single call, Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

What i need to do, is create or update in a single call, a parent and many childs.
To make it simpler, an equivalent problem would be as follow:
Supose i have a **classroom** and **teachers**, between them there is a relation called **course**. So the models whould be:

```
class Classroom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :courses
  has_many :teachers, through: :courses
end


class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses
  has_many :classrooms, through: :courses
end


class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :classroom
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

I need to create or update, in a single call, a classroom and all the courses. So i received from the frontend a json as follow:

```
{
    "name": "classroom_1",
    "courses": [
        {
            "name": "course1",
            "teacher_id": "teacher_1"       
        },
        {
            "name": "course2",
            "teacher_id": "teacher_2"       
        },
        {
            "name": "course3",
            "techear_id": "teacher_3"       
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be a good solution for this kind of problems? and how can i do it in Rails 5 ?

Comment: Nested Attributes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: thank you, i will check that info.